# Вопрос по MVC PHP

Tags: php

Пишу сайт. "Заморозился" на одном моменте)

Мне нужно вывести меню в навигационное меню на сайте.

Мне для этого нужно создать контроллер MenuController?

Или отдельно функцию для вывода меню? Подскажите!

Comment: нужно создать класс виджет MenuWidget

Comment: в какой-нить отдельной папке?

Comment: @vinnie да, если вы работали с фреймворками, то там же есть папки для виджетов components. Виджет должен быть доступен везде